# How can I add the value of a single Cell from Access database to a string variable

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable, dataadapter

As the title says I have a MS Access database from where I need to find a specific dataset determined by a String Value. the reason for having to do this is so I can find the value of a single cell in this datase which has to be used as a path to find a certain file. my approach so far is the following:

```
 Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ExaptLokal.accdb")
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim sql As String
 sql = "SELECT NC_KEY FROM EXAPT_NC_KOPF_DATEN WHERE NC_PROGRAMM_NAME =" & ProgrammNr.Text.ToString
        MsgBox(sql)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        fullpath = dt.ToString
```

at the end I would like to have the result from my SQL Query as the value of my "fullpath" variable but so far the `da.Fill(dt)` row is giving me a hard time saying there is a conflict with the datatype.

Is the datatable even needed in this case or might I be able to skip that step and get the result of the query directly in the fullpath variable?

Thanks to everyone in advance

Edit: Thanks for the help (though not the friendliest but who am I to judge) I finally got it to work with the `Execute Scalar` method. I would just wish newbies to this website would be greeted a little better lol
have a great day

Comment: Assuming that your query always returns a row. To retrieve the value you could do it this way: `fullpath = dt.Rows(0)("NC_KEY")`. If not, you could check if rows were returned by If dt.Rows.Count <> 0 Then ...

Comment: If you had done the research you should have before posting this question, you'd know that the way to get a single value from a database is to call `ExecuteScalar` on a command object. Even if you hadn't done that research, you should at least know how to get a value out of a `DataTable`. This site is supposed to be for stuff that you can work out despite doing the research, not as a substitute for that research. You'll also find that, unless `NC_PROGRAMM_NAME` has a numeric data type, your SQL code will generate a syntax error. learn to use parameters in queries.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for the info about the executeScalar I'll try to look into that more. and btw I have fondled with this problem for approx. 4 hours now with no conclusion and was getting desperate which is why I asked here. Also I only started working with vb.net a week  ago so I still have a lot to learn and don't even really know the basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the connection string to a class level variable so you can use it in other methods.

I separated your data access code from your user interface code passing the value from the text box to a function that returns the path.

I changed your select statement to use parameters. **Always** use parameters to avoid sql injection and avoid errors.

Use `Using...End Using` blocks to ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed. This `Using` block covers both the command and the connection.

You can pass the `.CommandText` and the `.Connection` directly to the constructor of the command.

When adding parameters to the parameters collection you provide the parameter name, the datatype form the database, and the size of the field. I had to guess at the type and size so, check your database for the actual values.

Since you are expecting a single value you can use `.ExecuteScalar`.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ExaptLokal.accdb"

Private Function GetPath(ProgrammNr As String) As String
    Dim fullpath As String
    Dim sql = "SELECT NC_KEY FROM EXAPT_NC_KOPF_DATEN WHERE NC_PROGRAMM_NAME = @ProgrmmNr"
    Using conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProgrmmmNr", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ProgrammNr
        conn.Open()
        fullpath = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString
    End Using
    Return fullpath
End Function
```

Usage...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fullpath = GetPath(ProgrammNr.Text)
End Sub
```